# Rails belongs_to relationship not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, belongs-to

Currently I am having issues with the belongs_to relationship between my Page model and my Companies model.

I receive the following error message when I am on the Page show.erb.html and I am accessing @page.company.id: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

This error message with and without the attr_accessor method in the companies model.

Page Model:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

Company Model:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :id, :name
    has_many :pages

end
```

Companies Migration:

```
class CreateCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :companies do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Pages migration:

```
class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pages do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :companies, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a page has a single company, your page migration should use:

```
t.references :company, index: true
```

(singular) instead of :companies (plural). This should allow rails to populate it properly.

Comment: Right answer! I'll write a follow-up to provide some context

Answer (score 1):

**Associations**

As Rails is designed to run on a [relational database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) stack, you have to appreciate the role of this structure plays in defining & creating the [ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) in your models.

To give you some ideas - [ActiveRecord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) is actually something known as an ["ORM" (Object Relationship Mapper)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) - meaning that it will manage the *relationships* between "objects" in your app. As Rails, by virtue of being built on top of Ruby, is [*object orientated*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), ActiveRecord plays an integral role in managing the relationships between your objects

The problem you're referring to is how to construct these relationships correctly:

---

**Models**

The answer to your question is:

```
#app/models/page.rb
Class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | company_id | other | attributes | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :company
end

#app/models/company.rb
Class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | title | other | page | attributes | created_at | updated_at
   has_many :pages
end
```

To demonstrate what the tables should look like, you can use this [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association):

[image]

This means that in reference to your question, you can either use `Martin`'s answer, or just add the `company_id` column manually (we do that):

```
class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pages do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :company_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

---

**Datatables**

Some other information information you should know:

1. Rails builds your associations with [`foreign_keys`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) - whenever you create a "relationship" in your Models, all it does it trigger ActiveRecord to identify the `foreign_key` for the association:

[image]

2. Finally, you also need to appreciate that the identification of "records" in a datatable is determined by the [`primary key`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key) it has. Every time you load an object in Rails, it's actually looking into the database for the corresponding `id` it has

This means if you wish to identify records in Rails, you need to make sure they have a `primary key` in the database

Comment: That is a far lengthier answer than required but it is a good guide for those who need it in the future.

Company instead of Companies would have sufficed.